# django model ManyToManyField not going through Manager

Tags: django, django-models, django-managers

I have 3 models.

```
class Poll(model):
     title = models.CharField()
     options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, through='PollOption', null=True, blank=True)

class Option(model):
     title = models.CharField()

     #also declared a manager, which return queryset from a specified database "abc"
     objects = OptionManager()

class PollOption(model):
     poll = ForeignKey(Poll)
     option = ForeignKey(Option)

     #also declared a manager, which return queryset from a specified database "abc"
     objects = PollOptionManager()
```

Assume that i have an instance of `Poll`, say `p`. 
If i perform `p.options.all()`, it's not going through the manager, where i have the database specified. Instead, it's fetching values from Default database.

Please help. Hope my question is clear. Else, i can clarify your questions.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set `use_for_related_fields = True` as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#managers-for-related-objects).